# Add videos to YouTube playlist without having end user sign in

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, playlist, google-apps-for-education

I use YouTube for Education and I would like to create a page where users (teachers) can submit YouTube video links and those videos be automatically added to my organizations playlist. I looked at the API, but I can't find a way for a video to be added to my playlist without giving the end users the username and password to my organization's Google account. Is this possible? Is so, could someone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/) for this purpose. They can upload or submit uploaded videos to your playlist.